# Put numpy arrays split with np.split() back together

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have split a numpy array like so:

```
x = np.random.randn(10,3)
x_split = np.split(x,5)
```

which splits x equally into five numpy arrays each with shape (2,3) and puts them in a list. What is the best way to combine a subset of these back together (e.g. `x_split[:k]` and `x_split[k+1:]`) so that the resulting shape is similar to the original x i.e. (something,3)?

I found that for k > 0 this is possible with you do:

```
np.vstack((np.vstack(x_split[:k]),np.vstack(x_split[k+1:])))
```

but this does not work when k = 0 as `x_split[:0] = []` so there must be a better and cleaner way. The error message I get when k = 0 is:

> ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate

Comment: What about `np.vstack(x_split[:k] + x_split[k+1:])`?

Comment: What's messy about handling the `k=0` case as something special.  We do that kind of edge-condition testing all the time.  Don't you?

Comment: @hpaulj because to me this problem seemed simple enough that I thought I must be missing something obvious - please see Paul Panzer's comment and Crazy Ivan's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by Paul Panzer is right on target, but since NumPy now [gently discourages `vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), here is the `concatenate` version:

```
x = np.random.randn(10, 3)
x_split = np.split(x, 5, axis=0)
k = 0
np.concatenate(x_split[:k] + x_split[k+1:], axis=0)
```

Note the explicit axis argument passed both times (it has to be the same); this makes it easy to adapt the code to work for other axes if needed. E.g.,

```
x_split = np.split(x, 3, axis=1)
k = 0
np.concatenate(x_split[:k] + x_split[k+1:], axis=1)
```

Comment: With a focus on array concatenate, it is easy to miss this cleaner list join option.

Answer (score 0):

`np.r_` can turn several slices into a list of indices.

```
In [20]: np.r_[0:3, 4:5]                                                                                                
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 2, 4])                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
In [21]: np.vstack([xsp[i] for i in _])                                                                                 
Out[21]:                                                                                                                
    array([[9, 7, 5],                                                                                                              
           [6, 4, 3],                                                                                                              
           [9, 8, 0],                                                                                                              
           [1, 2, 2],                                                                                                              
           [3, 3, 0],                                                                                                               
           [8, 1, 4],                                                                                                               
           [2, 2, 5],                                                                                                              
           [4, 4, 5]])                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [22]: np.r_[0:0, 1:5]                                                                                                
Out[22]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
In [23]: np.vstack([xsp[i] for i in _])                                                                                 
Out[23]:                                                                                                                
    array([[9, 8, 0],                                                                                                              
           [1, 2, 2],                                                                                                              
           [3, 3, 0],                                                                                                              
           [8, 1, 4],                                                                                                              
           [3, 2, 0],                                                                                                              
           [0, 3, 8],                                                                                                              
           [2, 2, 5],                                                                                                              
           [4, 4, 5]])
```

Internally `np.r_` has a lot of ifs and loops to handle the slices and their boundaries, but it hides it all from us.

If the `xsp` (your `x_split`) was an array, we could do `xsp[np.r_[...]]`, but since it is a list we have to iterate.  Well we could also hide that iteration with an `operator.itemgetter` object.

```
In [26]: operator.itemgetter(*Out[22])
Out[26]: operator.itemgetter(1, 2, 3, 4)
In [27]: np.vstack(operator.itemgetter(*Out[22])(xsp))
```